# How to make my Rails variable accessible to the entire app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session, rubygems, gmail

I'am using the Gmail Gem. I dont want to run Gmail.connect every time I will request data from gmail. I want to store the connection into a variable so I could access it anywhere into the application.

First attempt, I stored it into a global variable **@gmail_session** but I can't access the variable after when I tried to get it using a remote call.

Second attempt, I saved the connection in to a session variable **session[:gmail]**. I thought it would be the solution but I got this error message: **no marshal_dump is defined for class Thread**

Please help me store my Gmail Connection :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rails newb here, so there might be a better way out there, but here's my 20 on this..

Use the application_controller to create a method that loads the @gmail_session object there itself, that way its an instance var and available to all controllers/views.

For e.g.

```
def get_using_remote_call

  @gmail_session = //do some stuff

end
```

Then you can go ahead and add an after_filter in the application_controller that calls the function every time any of the controllers load, since after their first load in production they are cached, this should not pose a problem until your app gets 10000s visits a day...

Another way of doing the same thing would be to include a module in the config/libs and add the directory to autoload in your config/application.rb like this

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

This would auto load the module/class/whatever and then you can simply call the function `get_using_remote_call` and treat it as an object and chain it, or your could

```
@gmail_session = get_using_remote_call
```

OR simply use this in the after_filter/before_filter of your controller :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried your first suggestion but it fails. Here's what I did. In my application_controller, i have **login_gmain(account)** _create gmail variable_, **logout_gmail** _empty gmail variable_, and **current_gmail** _return gmail variable_. On the first load of the page, I current_gmail is able to get the active gmail session but after the remote call, the method current_gmail is not working. Even though I include after_filter :current_gmail. is there a good way to implement this? help me how :)